# VS 2005 Compile on Save C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, compilation

This is baffling me, I am unable to find this setting if it exists.
I am 90% sure that my code used to compile on save before.
I only started having this issue when using C#, .net worked fine.

But now I am only able to get rid of error lines etc, when choosing to enter debug mode.
For example when I have a method

```
public bool Method1(){
//No code added yet so I get a blue line saying return something
}
```

Even when I add what to return inside the method the line remains there on save. It only goes away when I build.

(This is just one example it seems to happen with lots of other things)

**EDIT** - In regards to options to compile on save.

The options in Build and Run are set Correctly

Comment: I have used Visual Studio .NET for nearly 7 years. I have never heard of this being possible.  I have used and still have a copy of Visual Studio .NET RC which was basically the 2001-2002 version.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about VS 2008? VS 2005 does not compile on save on my machine...

Comment: @Ramhound as in impossible to have error lines removed on save?

Comment: @Ramhound: VS 2008 and 2010 compile the code "on the fly" - I think that's what he's talking about. But I don't think this existed in VS 2005. At least it doesn't work with my VS 2005 here.

Comment: maybe it used to save on compile in 08. So its impossible to set that att in 05?

Comment: @Harper89 - What exactly do you mean "error lines removed on save"?

Comment: Yes, there's a combo box in the settings dialog under "Projects and Solutions > Compile and Execute" (sorry, using German VS 2005 - may be named differently, but should be easy to find) which controls what to save before compiling.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar - I currently have all three versions installed on my machine.  If by "on the fly" you mean indicate any errors without having to press the compile button I do believe you are correct about 2008 and 2010.  Of course after nearly a decade of using the program I still learn new things about it.  It also is hard to keep what changes made it in each version.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar - It does appear that VS2005 has the feature you were talking about.  The option is called "Build and Run" in the English version.  The feature allows you to define what happens you build the solution though.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited to show what I mean

Comment: Unless you have/had a special plugin that would do such thing. The only thing that comes close to what you are saying is in: Tool->Options. The Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, you can set the Before building option to Save all changes and the "On Run, when projects are out of date", Set it to "Always build"

Comment: @Harper89 - As I already indicated I have used VS for awhile now.  In all my time what you describe is exactly how it has worked.  I don't recall the default settings ever being different.  You might have had an add-on that gave you that capability.

Comment: @Alex The settings in Build and Run are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should produce a red underline and an entry in the Error List window: "not all code paths return a value".  It is produced by the IntelliSense parser, not the compiler.  Saving the file does *not* remove the error hint, only opening another project does.  And fixing the code of course.

There is a bug of sorts in this logic, in some cases the Error List doesn't get purged.  The only workaround I've seen is to restart Visual Studio.  I've only seen this with certain IntelliSense warnings and it only affects the Error List, not the editor.  I can't remember the exact type of warning that triggers this, it only ever happened when opening a project with code I didn't write.  These messages don't normally last long when I'm editing code.  Which is by far the best solution.

Comment: does seem to be something that is just strange.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be the other way around? Save on compile.
Anyway, you can simple change the ctrl+s key combination to build and save in the settings menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still no luck.